# Will sqoop import command work with Teradata Dbase 15?

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

I am new to Teradata.

For our project, we are currently using Teradata 13.10, and planning an upgrade to V. 15 soon.  The client is doing "Big Data Analysis"

To pull the data into Hadoop, they are using this command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/DATABASE=MY_DBASE --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --username MyUser --password Password4MyUser
```

Questions:
 1) Can anyone tell me if this command will work the same in V. 15 as it does now in 13.10? 
 2) Are there any issues (risks) to be aware of?

I realize that the Teradata Hadoop Connector is available.  However in the short-term, the client wants to use sqoop

While researching this myself, I found an article that seem relevant, but didn't really answer my question:
http://forums.teradata.com/forum/tools/tpt-15-00- teradata-hdp-sanbox-data-movement

Thanks a lot, I appreciate any help / guidance

Comment: You'll most likely need to upgrade the JDBC drivers to TeraJDBC__indep_indep.15.00.00.20.tar, but the Sqoop command will not change.

Comment: thanks a lot apesa, that is very, very helpful.  By the way, for anyone else reading this question.  I learned that Sqoop can be used with the Teradata Hadoop Connector.  It supposedly offers about a 30% increase in performance.